# Checking two strings for equality with one input and other from file

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, ifstream

[The dictionary file](http://train.usaco.org/usaco/namenumdict.txt)

This is my code. Here dict.txt is the linked file. The string search is initialized from a vector(possible) containing strings. I use getline to read from the file and store each line in the string temp. Now the problem is, when I execute `search == temp` the output is false, which should be true. I have to print the string which is found in the dictionary file. So I am extracting each line from the file and comparing but the equality is somehow bugged or I am making a problem somewhere.

```
    ifstream infile("namenumdict.txt");
    string search="", temp="";
    int k=0;
    for(int i=0; i<possible.size(); i++)
    {
        search=possible[i];
        while(getline(infile, temp))
        {
            if(search==temp)
            {
                fout<<temp<<endl;
                k++;
            }

        }
    }
```

I have checked by debugging that all things are working well. `search` is being initialized as well as `temp`.

Please let me know the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Unrelated: Did you intend to only search for the first entry in `possible[]` ? because once you encounter a string that is NOT in the file (from the point where you last left off your prior, if any, search) no further searches will succeed, as `infile` is at eof.

Comment: Yes, WhozCraig is right. Move the `possible` loop inside the `while (getline() ...)` loop

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes! I was trying it for the first time so did not think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possible gotchas. Windows ends lines with `\r\n`, but Linux just `\n`. If you're running this on Linux but using a file that comes from Windows, the string will contain the `\r` that appears before the `\n`. Check for `\r` at end of string and remove it.

The other possibility is that you're comparing "WORD" with "word". To handle that either lowercase both strings (or uppercase them both) before comparison.

Blast from the past: The `\r\n` comes from the ancient era of teletype machines. They had to do a carriage return (`\r`) to go back to start of line then a newline (`\n`) to drop to a new line.